# Neo4j: Replacement of CASE clause because of inefficiency?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a neo4j query which fetches all 1st degree & 2nd degree connections of a (User), and then fetches their places as owner or housemate.
I am collecting all the places and some other info with similar relationships between users through a CASE clause. But the issue is that the CASE clause takes more than 20 seconds to execute the 
query, which is really bad.

```
MATCH (n:User), (n)-[:connected_to*1..2 {status: 1}]-(sp:User),
           (sp)<-[:owner_of|house_mate]-(place:Place)
WHERE (ID(n) = {ID_n}) 
      AND NOT(n)<-[:owner_of|house_mate]-(place)
MATCH (place)-[tenant:owner_of|house_mate]->(u:User)
WITH DISTINCT place,
              type(tenant) AS type,
              u,
              CASE
                WHEN (n)-[:connected_to {status: 1}]-(u) THEN '1'
                WHEN (n)-[:connected_to*1..2 {status: 1}]-(u) THEN '2'
                ELSE '3'
              END AS connection
WITH place,
     collect({type: type, u: u, connection: connection}) AS tenants
RETURN place,
       [tenant IN tenants WHERE tenant.type = 'owner_of'   | [tenant.u, tenant.connection]][0] AS owner_array,
       [tenant IN tenants WHERE tenant.type = 'house_mate' | [tenant.u, tenant.connection]] AS house_mates_array
```

**Is there any efficient  way to return the connection among users??**

Answer (score 0):

This should be more efficient, as it uses `OPTIONAL MATCH` to perform the `(n)-[:connected_to*1..2 {status: 1}]-(u)` search once (instead of performing very similar searches up to two times in the `CASE` clause).

```
MATCH (n:user)-[:connected_to*..2 {status: 1}]-(:User)<-[:owner_of|house_mate]-(place:Place)
WHERE ID(n) = {ID_n} AND NOT(n)<-[:owner_of|house_mate]-(place)
MATCH (place)-[tenant:owner_of|house_mate]->(u:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[ct:connected_to*..2 {status: 1}]-(u)
WITH place,
     collect({
       type: type(tenant),
       u: u,
       connection: CASE SIZE(ct)
         WHEN 1 THEN '1'
         WHEN 2 THEN '2'
         ELSE '3'
       END}) AS tenants
RETURN place,
       [t IN tenants WHERE t.type = 'owner_of'   | [t.u, t.connection]][0] AS owner_array,
       [t IN tenants WHERE t.type = 'house_mate' | [t.u, t.connection]] AS house_mates_array
```

Comment: Thanks for answer @cybersam, after doing what you suggested it became bit more faster 3-4 seconds but still around 18 seconds to respond. For the most of cases its taking average 0.5 sec but with  high no. of records its not efficient